# MS Windows system date time and an apps licence

Tags: c#, .net, windows, systemtime

I plan to check MS Windows system date time periodically to see if the app licence is expired.

So what if the user will increase system timer always? 
And in this case is any way to know real date-time?

What if computer is offline but in some network still and can we somehow get date-time? Let's say from switch, router or may be MS Windows... Is there a way just to look around any and get possible timer resource (not WEB)?

Thank you for any clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the end user wants to pretend it's the stone age, you can't tell otherwise without exposure to external resources (web...).

Answer (score 2):

Save the consumption of minutes to disk, instead of checking against a hard date constantly. Then winding back the clock won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is a database application, You can save the current date in the database column. The system date is always go forward & not backward. If the system date is older than value in that database column, You can terminate the application and prompt it has been expired. & If it is not a database application you can save that value in the application settings in the exe file.